# Print contents of ModalPanel

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is it possible to print just the contents of `<rich:modalPanel`>?

Comment: print the content of richmodalPanel  ? you mean you want to print it in actual printer??

Comment: Yeah, say if user clicks on an icon or command button content in modalpanel will be sent to printer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wrap all the content of rich:modalpanel in a div then use following javascript snippet to do your work, of course it is not standard. add a print button in richmodal panel on click call this function of javascript

```
function PrintContent()
{
var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('divtoprint');
var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow",
"width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
WindowObject.document.close();
setTimeout(function(){
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close();
},6000);
}
```

source: http://www.isolutionteam.co.uk/printing-contents-of-a-div-using-javascript/

Comment: Source: http://www.isolutionteam.co.uk/printing-contents-of-a-div-using-javascript/, even including those invalid quotes.

Comment: OK, tried that code but when I click on my icon it opens a blank page for printing. However there is content in my modalpanel which it's not printing

Comment: This is what I use:                                      <h:graphicImage value="../images/Print.png" width="30" height="30" onclick="PrintContent();" />

Comment: @En-Motion  yes you can use this picture to represent printer button. BTW let me know once you get done with this

Comment: It opens the print page dialog fine, but as I said a blank page is printed which is incorrect

Comment: @En-MotionTry debugging, try to alert() content of DIV in which you have put all the data that is supposed to be printed, also check this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=20162

Comment: @org.life.java - Thanks very much. All seems to be working now.

Comment: @En-Motion If you have added anything special that is not listed here please let us know

Comment: It works for me. It does not pick up the stylesheet from parent. Else prefect!

Comment: And to link the stylesheet add this WindowObject.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-css-.css">') after WindowObject.document.write();

Comment: I added the WindowObject.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap.css">'); but there is no effect on the page
I can see the style code in opened window by right click -> view page source
but the browser can't render it.