# How can i print the content of the Modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to print the contents of the model window but my code prints the contents of the parent window instead.  Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Any source code, what have  you tried?

Comment: <a id="printlink" href="printpage.php" title="1" rel="modal" class="fancybox"  onmouseover="changelink()" >print</a>

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;">print</a>

Answer (score 2):

this will help you :

[print a modal window not the rest of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247534/print-a-modal-window-not-the-rest-of-the-page)

Comment: This is an approach using CSS classes. http://www.ozkary.com/2015/06/angularjs-print-bootstrap-modal-content.html